# How can I determine the current version number of an application with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, debian, aptitude

Say I have python-twisted installed.

```
sudo apt-get -V check python-twisted
```

does not show the version number, just

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

How do I get apt-get to print the currently installed version number for an application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt-get` is the wrong tool for that.

`dpkg -l python-twisted` shows the version number as part of a human-friendly listing with possibly truncated columns. For parseable output, use `dpkg-query -W python-twisted`, or `dpkg-query -W -f '${version}\n' python-twisted` to get just the version number.

`apt-cache policy python-twisted` shows what version of the package is installed as well as any version that is available for installation.

These are all about deb package versions, not python library module versions. The package version often follows the library module version, but it's not an obligation.

Answer (score 9):

I figured out you can get the version number of a python package (not anything) by just saying

```
python
>>> import twisted
>>> print twisted.version
[twisted, version 10.0.0]
```

small problem solved. general problem forgotten

Comment: Then you asked the wrong question. This topic might still be interesting for others; try to accept a solution for your original question if someone posts it.

Comment: For `numpy`, you need `print numpy.version.version`.