# How do I determine the version of OpenOffice from the command line in Ubuntu and OS X

Tags: macos, ubuntu, openoffice

How can I determine which version of open office is installed?
I'd like to be able to issue this command on an Ubuntu machine as well as a Mac OS X machine.

Comment: possible half dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/222017/how-can-i-determine-the-current-version-number-of-an-application-with-apt-get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the contents of the file `versionrc`. It's installed next to the binaries and its content is the following (on OS X):

```
$ cat versionrc 
[Version]
AllLanguages=en-US
buildid=330m20(Build:9567)
ExtensionUpdateURL=http://updateexte.services.openoffice.org/ExtensionUpdateService/check.Update
OOOBaseVersion=3.3
ProductBuildid=9567
ProductMajor=330
ProductMinor=20
ProductSource=OOO330
UpdateID=OpenOffice.org_3_en-US
UpdateURL=http://update36.services.openoffice.org/ProductUpdateService/check.Update?pkgfmt=dmg
UpdateUserAgent=<PRODUCT> (${buildid}; ${_OS}; ${_ARCH}; BundledLanguages=${AllLanguages})
```

On OS X, it's in `/Applications/OpenOffice.org.app/Contents/MacOS/versionrc` (depending on your installation path, of course).

In the RedHat 32 bit download, it's provided by `openoffice.org3-3.3.0-9567.i586.rpm` and is in `/opt/openoffice.org3/program/versionrc`.

---

Alternatively, run `soffice -h` (in the same directory as `versionrc`, if it's not on your path as e.g. on OS X):

```
$ ./soffice -h 2>&1 | head -n1
OpenOffice.org 3.3  330m20(Build:9567)
```

<sup>Filtered to remove help on `soffice`'s command line arguments.</sup>

Comment: On OS X, you could also read the `CFBundleGetInfoString` from `Info.plist`.